# inner join combined with a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our databases we have crewmembers and non-crewmembers. Each crewmeber and non-crewmember can have friends.

for example a crewmember is befriended with 4 crewmembers and 2 non-crewmembers.

What I would like to know is the avarage number of non-crewmembers our crewmembers with AirlineCode=LH have.

We have two tables involved:

AppUser: where the user data are stored.

Here we have the Cells 
AppUser.IsCrew (0 = non-crewmembers and 1 = crewmember)
AppUser.AirlineCode (sting of some sort)

Follower: Friends list stored

Follower.FromUserId 
Follower.ToUserId

There we store that AppUser.Id = 1 has 5 friends and follows Follower.ToUserId 3,4,5 and so on

Problem here is and I don't even know how to start:

Query which checks

a) All AppUser.IsCrew=1 and has Airline.Code=LH
b) Check in Follower table how many users they follow but only the ToUserId who are in AppUser.IsCrew have = 0

And somehow return a average number

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What's the specific database engine? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc.

Comment: we use a microsoft sql server

Comment: The table design is very unclear, can you clarify it and add some example data to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to count how many non-crewmembers friends each crewmember person has. Make sure you also count all crewmembers even if they don't have any friend.

Then it's a matter of averaging those counts. The query should look like:

```
with x as (
select
    c.id, count(n.id) as nc_total
  from AppUser c
  left join Follower f on f.FromUserId = c.id
  left join AppUser n on f.ToUserId = n.id and n.isCrew = 0
  where c.isCrew = 1
    and c.AirLineCode = 'LH'    
  group by c.id    
)
select avg(nc_total) from x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I need. One question: In the table AppUser I have also a cell "LastActivityDate", if we let aside the averaging. How can I "deselect" all the user with an activity date later than x from the result of the query above?

Comment: @Andreas AppUser is used twice. If you want to add an extra "filtering condition" for the **crewmember** AppUser (`c`), then add it in the `WHERE` section. Maybe something like `and c.LastActivityDate < x`. However, if you want to add the filtering condition to the **non-crewmember** (`n`), then append it to the `ON` clause of that specific join.